# Find the 2nd to last or nth to last value in a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to find the 2nd to last or nth to last value in a column, I already have a formula that works perfectly for my needs for finding the last value and I'm hoping there is a way to modify it to allow for the nth to last value to be found but as of yet I cant figure that out. Here it is:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(1-ISBLANK(B:B)),B:B)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below formula (note: this is an array formula, you need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> for it to work properly instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd> alone):

```
=INDEX(B:B,LARGE(IF(B:B<>"",ROW(B:B)),2))
```

Change the last `2` to `3` to get the 3rd from last non-blank value. The above formula works even if there are blanks in the columns between the non-blank values.

`IF(B:B<>"",ROW(B:B))` basically fetches the row number for non-blank rows, then `LARGE` picks the largest, or 2nd largest, etc depending on the value used at the end, to get the *n*th row you are looking for.

`INDEX` just picks the value from that row.

Comment: If you use entire column references in such a construction you are forcing Excel to calculate an enormous amount of additional, unnecessary cells. For example, if in fact you only have data extending to row 1000, just one instance of that formula is being forced to calculate more than 2 million cells more than are actually necessary, an astonishing amount for a single formula.

Comment: @XORLX The same is true for OP's original formula so I guessed the scope of the formula was already known, but just in case, it's good to be mentioned again. I'd be happy to know of an alternative formula that avoids such overheads.

Comment: True, but I can't imagine that the OP has data which extends beyond row 1 million! In such cases there are no viable non-array processing constructions available - all I can suggest is that you choose a suitably low upper bound on the end row reference. Even if this value is still necessarily large, e.g. 100,000, that's still saving on 900,000 calculations.

Answer (score 0):

```
 =INDEX(B:B, COUNTA(B:B) -D1 +1, 1)  
 =OFFSET(B:B, COUNTA(B:B) -D1, 0, 1, 1)
```

Where D1 contains your value 'N'.
These will both return the Nth value from the bottom of column B, assuming that there are not any blank cells between B1 and the final row of your list.

Comment: there is blanks and text between my data, hence using my original formula, which is the only formula i have made that will work